# How to open ownCloud client with Qt creator?

Tags: owncloud

I have the same issue as [this](https://forum.owncloud.org/viewtopic.php?t=29838) guy, and can't find any working solution over the web,  for windows 10 x64.

1st try- Windows development build,  for windows 10.
**Error:** qt5webkit not found, when building the client (step 7 of the manual)
Tested with Qt 4.8/5.6/5.7 and MinGW 4.9/5.3

2nd try- Linux build(Ubuntu 14.04). 
**Error:** qtkeychain-dev not found. It sais something about qtkeychain in the Generic Build Constructions, but I don't understand how to do it.

3rd try- Open the git project with Qt Creator or eclipse. Don't know how.

4th-  I'm thinking to programm my client using ownCloud client api and Java or C++, if I can't get to work the 3rd try.

I know stackoverflow is not the indicated for this kind of question, but I can't find help anywhere. Any thing/idea/opinion would be gratefull.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! (1) Please read the description for a tag before applying it to your question. The [tag:git] tag is for questions about Git usage and workflows, not programming questions that happen to involve a Git repo. (I've [edited](//stackoverflow.com/help/editing) your question to remove it.) (2) Qt is an application framework, maybe you mean Qt Creator? (3) Rather than just say your attempts "failed", please add some details about [what you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) and what failed. See also [ask].

Comment: Thx for comment. Updated.